# Route Name for HttpGet attribute Name for base generic controller class in asp.net core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-routing

I have a generic controller, which have several derived controller classes. but I cannot figure out how to handle the HttpGet's ***route name*** since it require constant.

```
[HttpGet("{id}", Name ="should not hard coded here for derived class")]
 public virtual async Task<IActionResult> Get(int id)
```

I need the route name because in my HttpPost function I want to return CreatedAtRoute() which require HttpGet's ***route name***

The route name cannot be hard coded because all the derived class need to have a different route name.

**here is the base controller**

```
public abstract class BaseController<TEntity, TContext> : Controller where TEntity : BaseOptionType, new() where TContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly IGenericRepository<TEntity, TContext> _repository;
    private readonly ILogger<BaseGenericOptionTypesController<TEntity, TContext>> _logger;
    public BaseController(IGenericRepository<TEntity, TContext> repository, ILogger<BaseController<TEntity, TContext>> logger)
    {
        _repository = repository;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
    [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "should not hard code here for derived class")]
    public virtual async Task<IActionResult> Get(int id)
    {
        var optionType = await _repository.FindByIdAsync(id);
        if (optionType == null)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"[ID not found]");
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Ok(optionType);
    }
}
```

**Here is the Derived Controller**

```
[Route("api/v1/DerivedControllerA")]
public class DerivedControllerA : BaseController<TimeOff, HRContext>
{
    public DerivedControllerA(IGenericRepository<TimeOff, HRContext> repository, ILogger<DerivedControllerA> logger)
        : base(repository, logger)
    {

    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: This is an XY problem. You should [never use a base controller in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6119341/). See [Cross-Cutting Concerns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/actions#cross-cutting-concerns).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I will not argue with NightOwl888 about use of base controllers in MVC. There are pros and cons, and I've dealt with the projects where use of base controllers was justified.

As regards original question, seems like the easiest way to get around this problem is to use `CreatedAtAction` instead of `CreatedAtRoute`. `CreatedAtAction` does not require you to name your routes, you could just use `Get` action name from base controller. If `CreatedAtAction` is called from `DerivedControllerA`, it will produce the URL for `Get` action in `DerivedControllerA`, and if it's called from `DerivedControllerB`, it will produce the URL for `Get` action in `DerivedControllerB`. So seems like shift to  `CreatedAtAction` covers your use case pretty well.

Here is a sample call to `CreatedAtAction`:

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual IActionResult Post(/* ... */)
{
    //  Create and save an instance in repository
    //  var createdObject = ...;

    return CreatedAtAction(nameof(Get), new
    {
        //  Put actual id here
        id = 123
    }, createdObject);
}
```

The common mistake is to call overload of `CreatedAtAction` with 2 parameters. This version takes created object for response body, not the route values, which often results to `No route matches the supplied values` error. If you don't want to return representation of created resource in the response, you could pass `null` as 3rd parameter:

```
    return CreatedAtAction(nameof(Get), new
    {
        //  Put actual id here
        id = 123
    }, null);
```

If for some reason you want to stick with `CreatedAtRoute` call, the only possible solution that comes to my mind is to have distinct action in each derived class which just calls to base method with the actual logic:

```
[Route("api/v1/DerivedControllerA")]
public class DerivedControllerA : BaseController<TimeOff, HRContext>
{
    // ...

    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
    [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "RouteForDerivedControllerA")]
    public virtual Task<IActionResult> Get(int id)
    {
        return base.Get(id);
    }
}

public abstract class BaseController<TEntity, TContext> : Controller where TEntity : BaseOptionType, new() where TContext : DbContext
{
    // ...

    public virtual async Task<IActionResult> Get(int id)
    {
        // Actual logic goes here
    }
}
```

Such solution however devalues use of `BaseController` in fact.

Comment: CreatedAtAction() does it.  Thanks!